# Merging two datasets which have 1 column in common

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dataset dsvalue that has columns Id and views. An other dataset has quite a number of columns including Id. So for each id in dataset ds, i should add a new column "Views" and merge it with views from dsvalue.

How is it possible. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You mean like SQL left join or inner join?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [`DataSet.Merge method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4swwh51k.aspx). You must have the `PrimaryKey` property defined on at least one of the DataTables in order to properly merge rows with equivalent IDs.

```
DataColumn Id = new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int));
// add Id to table... then set it as the PrimaryKey
dsvalue.Tables["tableName"].PrimaryKey = new[] { Id };

// merge
dsValue.Merge(dsOther);
```